# Before/In front of

Tags: word-choice, difference, american-english

I'd like to know if "before" and "in front of" is equally common in a sentence like this in American English? Is one more formal than the other?

> Elina stands before/in front of a vending machine, considering her options.

Answer (score 2):

The ***before / in front of*** distinction (when they have essentially the same *meaning*, which certainly isn't always the case<sup>1</sup>) isn't really about "formality". Mostly it's just that *to stand **before** [something]* has been [in long-term decline](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he%20stood%20before%2Che%20stood%20in%20front%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20stood%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20stood%20in%20front%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20stood%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20stood%20in%20front%20of%3B%2Cc0) by comparison with *to stand **in front of** [it]*. This doesn't create a very *strong* distinction, but ***before*** in such contexts is at least *slightly* "stilted / dated / old-fashioned".

In practice, I suspect the vast majority of native speakers would use ***by*** (or even ***at***) in the exact cited context.

---

In *other* contexts, *to stand **before** X* is the preferred preposition where ***X*** represents an "audience" (that *interacts* with the subject, rather than just being "nearby"). Particularly, a *judgmental* audience - *to stand **before** a jury* is often a "metaphorical" reference to being under scrutiny, whereas *to stand **in front of** a jury* might just be about actual relative positions in space.

---

<sup>1</sup> There's also the distinction reflected in the time-worn pun ***"How dare you break wind before the Queen!" - "I'm sorry, I didn't know it was her turn!***, playing on the fact that ***before*** can mean ***earlier in time***, as well as ***in the presence of, [physically] in front of***.

Comment: preferred by who? someone made quite a gaff in front of that dastardly judgmental audience

Comment: Preferred by *the average Anglophone speaker / writer*, as supported by my "in long-term decline" link above. Because there's a 5-word limit on search phrases in NGrams, I couldn't directly compare *stood before the court* and *stood in front of the court*, but I'm pretty sure the chart I *did* produce does accurately reflect a decline for that specific usage. It may also be worth noting that Google Internet claims over 500 hits for the text ***stand before a jury of my peers***, but just 8 hits for ***stand in front of a jury of my peers***.

Comment: stand before a judge. jury. one's peers is an idiom

Comment: Okay. [*(I) stand before you pleading for (some boon)*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stand+before+you+pleading+for%22&oq=%22stand+before+you+pleading+for%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.450796j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets a claimed 260 hits on Google, whereas [*(I) stand in front of you pleading for (whatever)*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stand+in+front+of+you+pleading+for%22&oq=%22stand+in+front+of+you+pleading+for%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.554486j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets ***no hits at all***.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to look at my answer which is nothing but just a perfect copy of the explanation of your country's media.

Comment: +1 This answer explains this annoying aspect of these terms: they can both mean the same thing. However, they are not used in the same context. People stand in front of [things]. And when those people stand before things, there had better be a good reason for it (literary, historical, etc.). That said, in everyday conversation *before* calls for a buzzer.

Answer (score 0):

Before is either a bit formal or could be used for stylistic effect, if used in this context.  She may well stand before the Bench in a Court of Law...

I would say that a vending machine would only warrant "standing in front of", in the normal course of events.

Comment: I agree but your answer is too "skinny". :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am not a native speaker, but this seems to be an easy task, so let's borrow the [**BBC's explanation**](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv222.shtml) about the difference between in front of and before.

As a preposition.

> **Before** is not normally used to refer to place. We normally use **in front of** to specify place the opposite of which is **behind**. Compare the following:
>
> Sam was sitting ***in front of my girlfriends*** in the cinema but ***behind my sister.***
>
> I was waiting patiently in the queue. ***In front of me*** there were about two hundred people and ***behind me*** a further three hundred.

---

> **Before** is normally used as a preposition to indicate **time**. Its opposite of which is **after:**
>
> Your brother arrived at the church shortly ***after*** three, but I distinctly remember saying to everyone: "You must be in your seats at or ***before*** three o' clock".
>
> Excuse me, I was here ***before*** you. I should therefore be ***in front of*** you in the queue.

---

> However, **before** is used to refer to **place** when it indicates **position in a list** or when it means **in the presence of somebody important**:
>
> K comes ***before*** L in the alphabet, but ***after*** J.
>   He had behaved so badly in school that he was brought ***before*** the headmistress.
>
> I was accused of dangerous driving but rather than pay the fine, I elected to appear ***before*** the local magistrates.

Note that in these last two examples **before** means **facing** and **not one behind the other.**

---

> **Before (conjunction or adverb)**
>
> **Before** is often used as **a conjunction** linking two clauses or as **an adverb** of time, meaning **at some time before now.**
>
> Give me a ring to let me know you are on your way ***before you leave the house.***
>
> Make sure you get to the church ***before the bride arrives.***
>
> ***Before she married Maurice,*** she went out with Austin for a couple of years.
>
> He was certain we had met ***before,*** but I was equally sure we hadn't, for I had never been there ***before.***
>
> Within two minutes of it starting, I realized that I'd seen this film ***before.***